# How can I find if a given RGB color is between a range of known colors?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, rgb, pixel

Here's some code to try and demonstrate what I'm trying to do:

```
def check_color(color):

    green_start = (40, 40, 40)
    green_end   = (70, 70, 70)

    if color > green_start and color < green_end:
        return True

    return False

if check_color((60, 50, 60)):
    print 'the color is "green"'
```

Using PIL, I'm trying to detect if a given color is 'green' (in this example). The colors are provided as an (R, G, B) tuple.

How can I perform the comparison?

Comment: 40,40,40 and 70,70,70 (everything where r=g=b) are certainly not green at all.

Comment: My made up ranges where just for example use

Answer (score 3):

Converting your RGB value to another [color model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_models) like [HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) and compare the Hue is probably helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You could select cutoff points for the colors. RGB colors are represented by 3 values which tell the amount of red, green and blue to mix to make the color.  You need to decide which mixtures you consider to be a certain color.

For example you could say that a color is red as long as the values of green and blue are less than half the value of red. i.e.: (r = 100, g = 49, b = 49) would be red but (r=100, g=49, b=50) would not be because 50 is not less than half the value of red, 100.  Likewise (r=50, g=23, b=24) would be red.  You could apply the same rule to green and blue.

pseudocode:

```
def get_color(color)
    r,g,b = color
    if g < r/2 and b < r/2
        return "red"
    if r < g/2 and b < g/2
        return "green"
    if r < b/2 and g < b/2
        return "blue"
```

This only covers red, green and blue and you would want to adjust the rules to fit your needs.  You could also make other rules to find other colors like yellow or purple, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You could try checking each color component separately:

```
return all(s <= c <= e for c, s, e in zip(color, green_start, green_end))
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/jfPsS)

Comment: That seems to do what I need, cheers. Now I just need to find my color ranges

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
tuple1 = (1,2,3)
tuple2 = (1,2,4)

print (tuple1 == tuple2)    # False

print (tuple1 < tuple2)      # True

print (tuple1 > tuple2)      # False
```

More examples in https://howtodoinjava.com/python/compare-tuples/